# how to upload image as byte array to Rest web-service using http post method in android

Tags: android

I created app which can upload the images to the web-service. In that, how can I upload use the image as byte[] array while uploading image using HTTP post method to rest web-service.
How to pass the byte[] array to web-service along with file name and file length?

Comment: There is plenty of reference are available in website. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Drawable d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.human_head);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
            byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
            entity.addPart("image", new ByteArrayBody(bitmapdata,".png")); 


    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
         HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, WebService.getInstance(Constants.WEB_SERVER).getLocalContext());
```